# Codeigniter installation in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to install the latest version of codeigniter in a subdirectory. That works so far. But now I want to remove the `index.php` from the url. So therefore I have this `.htaccess` file in the subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The name of the subfolder is `dev` and the webroot (the parent folder) is empty. There is just an `index.html` file in it.

So this is resulting in this structure:

```
/var/www/
    index.html
    dev/
        ci installation here
        .htaccess
```

and of course `mod-rewrite` is enabled.

Any ideas why it wont work?
I get an 404 Error when calling something like http://domain.tld/dev/login

Comment: What directory is the codeigniter index.php in?

Comment: the CI `index.php` file is in `dev`with the application ans system folder

Comment: The interesting thing is that it is working in the document-root (after changing `RewriteBase` to `/`).

Comment: ok... i fogot to activate AllowOverride ...

Answer (score 4):

You need two things.

In the `config.php`, configure `index_page` to be empty, so the URLs are created properly

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0
```

The access to the `system` and `application` directories is already prohibited by the `.htaccess` files in these subdirectories, delivered by Codeigniter.

Comment: Sorry but that one is not working. I Still get the 404 Error. Isn't there missing the `RewriteBase` anyway?

Comment: @Le_Morri I just duplicated your setup (directory structure, login controller, etc.) and it works for me. And there's no `RewriteBase` needed. There must be some other rule or directive, causing the 404 error.

Comment: @Le_Morri Just to clarify, your setup plus `index_page` empty and the `.htaccess`, I suggested.

Comment: The problem was actually not in the `.htaccess` nor int the `config.php`. The server-admin forgot to set `AllowOverride` to `all`. it was set to `none`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: Unfortunalty that one isn't working eigther.