# Codeigniter Remove .php and route to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

If a user follows this url:

```
http://localhost/events/info.php
```

How can I remove the .php extension via htaccess so the user gets routed to index.php and my Events Controller into the Info function? I basically want to create 301 redirects.

```
http://localhost/events/info
```

I have old indexed links that I need to redirect to my controller functions so I do not get 404s.

Comment: You really just need to read the excellent [CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) on URL structure.

Comment: I understand how the URL structure works. I have old indexed links that I need to redirect to my controller functions so I do not get 404s.

Comment: I see, however the original question did not state this issue. RewriteRules in your .htaccess file are your best to way to create 301 permanent redirects.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15844946/1741542

Answer (score 1):

use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/info/$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of CI you are using?

normally we already got like this without .php

```
http://localhost/events/info
```

To route to index.php (in view folder): you only need to do like this in your controller file.

**controllers/events.php**

```
function info(){
 redirect('events/index');
}

function index()
{
 $this->load->view('index.php');
}
```

Comment: he would to change it via the .htaccess file ;)

Comment: anyway , I learn something . Cool :)

Answer (score 0):

A 301 redirect can be achieved using `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 events/info.php http://localhost/events/info
```

You may find [this tool](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) useful for generating the redirects.

---

If you just want to route the URL: `http://localhost/events/info.php` to the `info` function in your `events` controller, then you don't *have* to remove `.php` from the URL, you can add a [route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) in `application/config/routes.php`.

```
$route['events/info.php'] = 'events/info';
```

If you haven't already then you must also remove `index.php`, [CodeIgniter's user guide explains how to do this.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

If you'd like to remove `.php` from all your URLs to make them look cleaner, then there a lots of resources available, including [other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635748/604532).